# How to modify the colors of a raster map to use only one color in varying shades?

Tags: raster, grass-gis, color

I have a raster map in GRASS containing elevation values. I want to display the elevation values in only one color (specificaly blue) but in varying shades of blue. I tried the options in r.colors, but none of those displays the map in monochrome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In GRASS shell type:

```
> r.colors map=elevation color=rules 
> 0 white
> [your maximum elevation value] blue
> end
```

Comment: Or simply `0% white` `100% blue`.

Comment: I tried creating a shell script containing: `#!/bin/sh
r.colors map=raster_bulacanOriginal2 color=rules 
0 white
300 blue
end
` and GRASS just kept on freezing

Comment: It's not freezing, it's expecting input. If you want to use it in a shell script, you need to do something like `#!/bin/sh echo -e '0 white\n300 blue' | r.colors map=<mapname> color=rules rules=-`, which pipes the color rule to the `r.colors` command. The `rules=-` option tells `r.colors` to expect the rule from the pipe. Or you can save the color rule to a file, and use `r.colors map=<mapname> color=rules rules=<rulesfile>`.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed that the color for the rules only uses color names. Can ASCII colors be used? I tried assigning a HEX color to a certain value and it produced this error: `ERROR: bad rule (invalid color name): [-25 #00FFFF]`

Comment: According to http://grass.osgeo.org/grass62/manuals/html62_user/r.colors.html, you'd have to write '0 255 255' instead of '#00FFFF'.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I should have used decimal values instead of HEX.